# SQL update scripts taking too much memory and doesn't free it up

Tags: c#, sql

I have this piece of code that executes update scripts on the database. I have 20 .sql files that contains about 400 update scripts. The overall size of the files is around 60MB. When I execute all the update scripts, it eats up about 400 MB of RAM and doesn't free it. I'm looking for ways to optimize this code.

```
private void ExeCuteCommand(SqlConnection conn, string script, bool flag)
    {
        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand();
        command.Connection = conn;
        command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        command.CommandText = script;

        if (flag)
            command.ExecuteNonQuery();               
    }
```

**EDIT:**

This is the calling method, basicall what it does is loop through the files, get the contents and pass the contents to the `ExecuteCommand` method.

```
private void ExecuteUpdateScripts(SqlConnection conn)
    {
        int step = 1;
        foreach (string update in Directory.GetFiles(scriptDirectory, @"SCRIPT UPDATE ??.sql"))
        {
            string updateScript = File.ReadAllText(updateSQL);
            ExeCuteCommand(conn, updateScript, true);

            step++;
        }
    }
```

I have looked at the Visual Studio profiler and this is the line the consumes a lot of memory `command.ExecuteNonQuery();`

Comment: Perhaps .NET/C# isn't the best tool? Why not simply let [`sqlcmd.exe`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162773.aspx) execute the .sql scripts; you can write a `.bat` that loops through the .sql files in the directory.

Answer (score 1):

- As it seems you execute the `SqlCommand` only if `flag == true` so the first thing you should do is place a guard clause at the top of the method.
- The `SqlCommand` object implements the `IDisposable` interface, therefor you should enclose it in an `using` statement which takes care of the disposing of this object.
- the default value of the `CommandType` property is `CommandType.Text` so there is no need to assign it.
- there is a overloaded constructor, which takes the connection and the querystring so you should use it.
- `Execute` is not a compound word, so you shouldn't use `PascalCase` for this word. The method should be named `ExecuteCommand()`.
- a variable named `flag` does not describe what its purpose is. Much better would be `shouldBeExecuted`.
- you should always use braces `{}` although they are optional for single line `if` statements. Omiting them will lead to potential error prone code.

Applying these points will lead to

```
private void ExecuteCommand(SqlConnection conn, string script, bool shouldBeExecuted)
{
    if (!shouldBeExecuted) { return; }

    using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(script, conn))
    {
        command.ExecuteNonQuery();               
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the tips. But somehow the memory consumption is still not freed up. could it be the individual update scripts?

Comment: You would need to show (but not in the same question) the calling code. Also a good way to check what cause the memory consumption is to use a profiler.

Comment: I've updated the code. please see edit. thanks

Comment: `SqlConnection` should also be inside a `using`, so we'd need to see the code where the `SqlConnection` is created.

Comment: It could be individual update scripts. As @Heslacher mentioned, try to use sql profiler to see what is going on.

Comment: If you change the creation of the command to be `conn.CreateCommand()`, and assign the text inside the using statement, the input connection could be `IDbConnection` instead of forcing it to be a `SqlConnection`.